# Prove that$\{T_i{_j}, 1 ≤ i ≤ m, 1 ≤ j ≤ n\}$ spans $L(V,W)$

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

[image]

The exercise 2.4.21 is in the textbook linear algebra 4th edition by Stephen H. Friedberg Arnold J. Insel Lawrence E. Spence.

I want to ask some questions of the proof of the set $\{T_i{_j}: 1 ≤ i ≤ m,\ 1 ≤ j ≤ n\}$ spanning $L(V,W)$:

Give a $T\ \in\ L(V,W), \ v\ \in\ V$

$T(v) = \beta_1w_1 + \beta_2w_2+.....+\beta_mw_m$

$\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ = \beta_1T_1{_j}(v_j) + \beta_2T_2{_j}(v_j)+.....+\beta_mT_m{_j}(v_j)...(*)$

$T = \beta_1T_1{_j}+ \beta_2T_2{_j} + ....\beta_mT_m{_j}\ \in\ \{T_i{_j}: 1 ≤ i ≤ m,\ 1 ≤ j ≤ n\}$

1.By the (*) step, I wonder what "$v_j$" should we use in $T_i{_j}$ for different $v$?
Is it whatever we want to use or which one composes the $v$?

2.If I choose different v , the coefficients $\beta_x$ would also be different, but a theorem also says the T should be composed by unique coefficients of the basis, which implies the proof might be wrong?

[image]

Comment: Each $T_{i,j}$ satisfies $[T_{i,j}]_{\gamma}^{\beta}=E_{i,j}$. The mapping $T\to [T]_{\gamma}^{\beta}$ is an isomorphism between $L(V,W)$ and $M_{m\times n}$, and since $\{E_{i,j}\}$ are clearly a basis, so is $\{T_{i,j}\}$. Now try to work the proof by maybe thinking of matrices.

Comment: Use the command \in to write $\in$. Using \epsilon as you did is confusing.

Comment: @GBA So the proof I wrote is a incorrect way?

Answer (score 1):

This claim is false $T = \beta_1T_1{_j}+ \beta_2T_2{_j} + ....\beta_mT_m{_j}$.

Functions (transformations) are equal only if its values are equal for all v in the domain. And for linear transformations there is an advantage that is stated in Corollary to the Theorem 2.6 of the same book, that is they are equal only if its values are equal for all base vectors in the domain.

A hint is that you can determine T by what it does to the base vectors of V, use Theorem 2.6. to define T then try to prove that T is in the span of
$ \{ T_{ij}: 1 \leq i \leq m  , 1\leq j \leq n \} $.